# Having trouble understanding list comprehensions

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, pythagorean

I've just started learning haskell(literally, tonight!) and I'm having a little trouble understanding the logic of list comprehensions, more specifically the `<-` operator. A little example on [Learn You Some Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out) Finds all tuples that have a length less than 10:

```
ghci> let triangles = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], b <- [1..10], a <- [1..10] ]
```

my initial understanding was that these would all increment together, but after seeing the output I really dont understanding the **incrementing** method for these lists. Another example that seems to get me is:

```
ghci> let rightTriangles = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], b <- [1..c], a <- [1..b], a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

I would really appreciate a little explanation on these, thanks for your patience with my lack of haskell intelligence.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Read `[` as "list of", `|` as "for", `<-` as "in", `,` as "and".

The enumerations are done in *nested* fashion. `[ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], b <- [1..c], a <- [1..b], a^2 + b^2 == c^2]` is really

```
for c from 1 to 10 step 1:
   for b from 1 to c step 1:
      for a from 1 to b step 1:
          if (a^2 + b^2 == c^2):
             emit (a,b,c)
```

In Haskell though, the above is achieved by the following translation

```
[1..10] >>= (\c->               -- (a function of 'c', producing ...
  [1..c]  >>= (\b->               -- (a function of 'b', producing ...
    [1..b]  >>= (\a->               -- (a function of 'a', producing ...
      if a^2+b^2==c^2 then [(a,b,c)] else []
      -- or: [(a,b,c) | a^2+b^2==c^2]
      )))
```

so you really can see the nested structure here. `(>>=)` is nothing mysterious too. Read `>>=` as "fed into" or "pushed through", although its official name is "bind". It is defined (for lists) as

```
(xs >>= f) = concatMap f xs = concat (map f xs)
```

`f` here is called (by `map`) upon each element of `xs`, in order. It must produce *lists* so that they could be combined with `concat`. Since empty lists `[]` are eliminated on `concat` (e.g. `concat [[1], [], [3]] == [1,3]`) all the elements that do not pass the test are eliminated from the final output.

---

For the full translation see [section 3.11, List Comprehensions](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.11), of the Haskell 98 Report. In general a list comprehension may contain a pattern, not just a variable name. The comprehension

```
[e | pat <- ls, ...]
```

is translated as

```
ls >>= (\x -> case x of pat -> [e | ...] ;
                        _   -> [] )
```

where `pat` is some pattern, and `x` is a fresh variable. When there's a pattern mismatch, an empty list is produced (instead of a run-time error), and that element `x` of `ls` is skipped over. This is useful for additional pattern-based filtering, like e.g. `[x | Just x <- ls, even x]` where all the `Nothing`s in `ls` are quietly ignored.

Comment: Detailed and very clear, really helped me understand the material. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

`[ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], b <- [1..10], a <- [1..10] ]` means, for all combinations of (a,b,c) where a is in [1..10], b is in [1..10], c is in [1..10]

If you want the (1,1,1) (2,2,2) kinds, you should use `zip`: `zip [1..10] [1..10]` or for 3 lists, `zip3 [1..10] [1..10] [1..10]`

Comment: Or you could enable [Parallel List Comprehensions](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#parallel-list-comprehensions) and write `[(a,b,c) | c<-[1..10] | b<-[1..10] | a<-[1..10] ]`!

Answer (score 1):

I think of list comprehension syntax as Haskell's attempt to get [Set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Parallels_in_programming_languages) in the language. We use '[' rather than '{' and '<-' rather than '∈'. List comprehension syntax can even be [generalized](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#monad-comprehensions) to arbitrary monads.